# Trying to append a REST url in Angular upon button click.

Tags: angularjs, rest, ionic-framework

So I have the following factory/controller set up in an Ionic framework and it works fine. However, I want to provide three buttons that once clicked, change the locations - for example button one = LONDON, button two is NEW YORK and button three changes it to MADRID. I can do this currently by writing three factories and changing the API URL - hard coding it in, but it seems messy. I'm wondering if there's a way that the "click" can be linked to a param or something? I have searched and I've seen search, interpolation, and $resource tutorials, but nothing seems to be quite right.

```
.factory('eventService', function ($http) {
    var events = [];

    return {
        getEvents: function () {
            return $http.get('http://api.API.com/json/q=music&location=LONDON&app_key=XXX').then(function (response) {
                events = response.data.events;
                return response.data.events;
            });
        },
        getEvent: function (index) {
            return events.event[index];
        }
    }
})
```

//controllers

```
      .controller("GigsCtrl", function ($scope, eventService) {
        eventService.getEvents().then(function (events) {
            $scope.events = events;
        });
    })
```

//and each item is clickable and so on...

```
    .controller("GigDetailCtrl", function ($scope, $stateParams, eventService) {
        $scope.event = eventService.getEvent($stateParams.index);
        console.log("Second Controller says: Hello World - I work");
    })
```

It's probably a really easy solution and I just can't see the forest for the trees! Be gentle, I've only been doing this since December so pretty new to it!

This gets super close but still isn't really solved...[Get URL param in Express API from Angular UI-Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573189/get-url-param-in-express-api-from-angular-ui-router)

//buttons - each go to a new search page, which currently each has a factory but ideally I'd the act of clicking the button to alter the one "master" factory...

```
<ion-content class="padding">
    <div class="button-bar bar-dark">
        <a href="#/london" class="button">London</a>
        <a href="#/madrid" class="button">Madrid</a>
        <a href="#/newyork" class="button">New York</a>
```

Comment: Kyle. Please read your post once and rephrase it meaningfully and also what is the **trouble** you are facing? Update it to post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could pass in the value needed to modify the request url, something like:

```
getEvents: function (location) {

    var params ={
       q:'music',
       app_key: your_app_key,
       location: location ? location.toUpperCase() :'LONDON';//default
    };
     return $http.get('http://api.API.com/json/', {params: params}).then(function (response) {             
         return response.data.events;
     });
 }
```

Then in your state configuration use the location instead of index for more meaningful url display

Comment: Ahh this is almost it - It is so close but how would it would look at the HTML/Button side of things? I just can't quite see how to link params to the button click...

Comment: You do it using `$stateParams` and configuring the url with same in your state configuration...the url in config would look something like `url: 'music-list/:location'` and use `ui-sref="music-list-stateName({location:'MADRID'})"` in the html

Comment: I see! The same as i would have done for GigDetailCtrl pages...I'll try it! Thank you!